# Looking for a sci-fi graphic novel I read as a kid involving humanoid dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, dinosaurs, graphic-novel

I remember reading the book in 3rd grade. The main characters were a team of large humanoid dinosaurs that were fighting against a similar team of humanoid dinosaurs led by a large alien who had a similar appearance to Shredder from Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles.

One plot point I remember is the villainous team of dinosaurs stealing nuclear warheads from a US base somewhere in the Arctic. Another plot point involved the alien villain traveling back in time to the Cretaceous Period, fighting a T-Rex, then collecting some other dinosaurs to put in his ship (implied to be the future villainous team of dinosaurs he creates.)

The art style was similar to other comics coming out in the 2000s. I believe it released sometime in 2008 if I remember correctly. Fight sequences involved laser weapons and hand to hand combat, preventing a highly catastrophic event from happening such as a city being blown up, etc. There are humans in the story, mainly ones helping the main team of dinosaurs.

Answer (score 8):

Could this be [*Jurassic Strike Force 5*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/14654402) (2012)?

A team of dinosaurs, aided by humans, steal nuclear weapons. The head honcho is repeatedly described in reviews as being a Shredder ripoff.

> We've got what I can only refer to as the son of Rita Repulsa and The
> Shredder being freed from some kind of underground bunker in the
> arctic, and the moment he is out he damn near quotes Rita line for
> line before gathering up his mutant dinosaur troops and setting out to
> take over the world. And his troops seem to all be character tropes
> from old cartoons. The somewhat capable t-rex who leads the dino
> troops but is kind of a pushover in every fight he gets in? Well that
> sure reminds me of Genghis Rex. The hot pterodactyl chick looking to
> back stab her way up the ranks and assume command? Oh yeah, that would
> be Starscream. The agile twins who talk funny? Tomax and Xamot anyone?
> The two brutes who are dumb as a box of rocks and are only there to
> serve as muscle? I'm smelling Bebop and Rocksteady...

[image]

[image]